# Spring Security filters out every case

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have the following security configuration on a two page basic website.

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="permitAll"  />
    <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <form-login login-page='/login.jsp'
        default-target-url="/index.jsp"         
        username-parameter="name"
        password-parameter="password"/>
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
            <user name="user" password="user" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

I'm not using custom controllers, only using the default spring view resolution.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

When I try to access the default page `index.jsp` it redirects me to the `login.jsp` page as I expect, but when I put in the data of the form it doesn't send me to the `index.jsp` page redirecting me again to `login.jsp`. The form fields are defined with `name` as showin in the security config and the form `action` is `index.jsp`.

My `login.jsp` form:

```
<form method="post" action="<c:url value = '/index.jsp' />">
    <label for="inputEmail3">User</label>
    <input name="name" type="text" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="User name" required>

    <label for="inputPassword3">Password</label>
    <input name="password" type="password" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password" required>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Sign in</button>
    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Reset</button>
</form>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Could you show `login.jsp` ? (I assume there is one since you use custom parameter names)

Comment: I'm showing the form in login.jsp now.

Comment: And why should it do anything. Why is the form submitted to `index.jsp`? It should be something like `j_spring_security_check`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring security uses filters including for form login. By default, when it needs to authenticate a user, the `DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter` generates a page containing a HTML form, but you  can alse provide yours.

Then the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` intercepts the submission of the form, by default on the URL `j_spring_security_check`, and the form should be submitted with a POST or spring security will (by default) throws an Exception.

You should use a dedicate URL for the login form submission. If you do not like `j_spring_security_check` you can change it with the `login-processing-url` form-login attribute, but it should **not** be the same as the success URL.